# Including iostream errors

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have a question and I could not find a solution, so I ask here :)

I want to create an Foundation-based terminal application/script using Xcode-->Mac-->New-->Command Line Tool-->Foundation

This works and all, but then I want to ADD header.h files to my project.
One of this header.h files does the following:

```
#include <iostream>
```

This fails with the error: iostream file not found.

For a test I make a new c++ based terminla script and it does exactly the same:

```
#include <iostream>
```

But for some unknown reason it does not fail with an error.
Can anyone tell me, why the c++ script works to include and the objective c not?

objective c: .h file
c++: .cpp file
I renamed the .h to .cpp but then it does not find the NSString and such things.. any solution to use iostream and objective c?

I really need that, thanks

Comment: this is obvious, no need to tell me, but isnt there kinda objective-c++ I heard of that. also, why does .cpp find iostream file and .h not -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use both Objective-C and C++ (called Objective-C++) from within the same source module, then use the `.mm` file extension.

Comment: THANKS worked! I renamed main.m to main.mm and it let me compile! :) thanks a lot